# Exoplayer View not able to find player.prepare() function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Currently I am facing a problem with the new version of **Exoplayer**. Below is the code used for player start. In getPlayerStart() I am  passing url link. In initExoPlayer() I am initializing my **Exoplayer** but in earlier version of **Exoplayer** I am facing this problem:

### mExoPlayerView!!.player.prepare(mVideoSource):

Above function is showing not available

```
private fun getPlayerStart(urlLink: String) {
        if (playerMode) {
            val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, context!!.getApplicationInfo().packageName)
            val httpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, null, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true)
            val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, null, httpDataSourceFactory)
            Log.i("Video",urlLink)
            val daUri = Uri.parse(urlLink)
            val extractorsFactory = DefaultExtractorsFactory()
            mVideoSource = ExtractorMediaSource(daUri, dataSourceFactory,
                    extractorsFactory, null, null) as MediaSource?
        }
        initExoPlayer()

    }


 private fun initExoPlayer() {
        val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        val videoTrackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)
        val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl()
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(DefaultRenderersFactory(context), trackSelector, loadControl)
        mExoPlayerView!!.player= this.player
        player!!.addListener(this)

        mExoPlayerView!!.player.prepare(mVideoSource)
        mExoPlayerView!!.getPlayer().playWhenReady = true
    }
```

Comment: The logic seems to be ok... maybe you missed some import? Can you show compile-time stack-trace?

Comment: I have the full **ExoPlayer** library and am seeing the same issue. `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.2'`

Answer (score 2):

The `prepare()` method is part of the `ExoPlayer` interface which extends the `Player` interface.

The `PlayerView` only exposes the `Player` interface which does not have the prepare method. That's why you can't do `mExoPlayerView!!.player.prepare(mVideoSource)`.

However, the `ExoPlayerFactory`, which you are using, does return a `SimpleExoPlayer` instance which does implement the `ExoPlayer` interface:

```
SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(context), trackSelector, loadControl);
player.prepare(mediaSource);
```

Here are the class references of the `ExoPlayer` and `Player` interface, as well as the `SimpleExoPlayer`:

https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html
https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.html
https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html